# DBT : --vars option not overriding dbt_project.yml file value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have defined the variable in dbt_project.yml file and want to override the same when running the dbt model..But its not overriding and take the variable from yml file
getting this from log :

```
02:04:13  Database Error in model AUD_RECON_INPUT (models\AUD_RECON_INPUT.sql)
02:04:13    002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
02:04:13    Object 'ETS_REVAP02_DB_DEV.REVAP_AUDIT.ABC' does not exist or not authorized.
02:04:13
02:04:13  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1
```

Command used :

```
dbt run --select AUD_RECON_INPUT --vars '{"RECON_INPUT":"XYZ"}'
```

Comment: We need more info. Can you share the relevant parts of your dbt_project.yml and model files? Also, what shell are you using? Windows command prompt may not be parsing your command line arguments correctly.

Comment: @Sergiu We are facing the same issue where the Value passed during command line --vars is not being overwritten and in log we can see variables value being picked from project.yml File

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after `:`:

```
dbt run --select AUD_RECON_INPUT --vars '{"RECON_INPUT": "XYZ"}'
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference to support this?